# Badge Lineage - Time or dates on which badges were introduced

Tags: discussion, badges

Hey Everyone,

Is there a page outlining the dates on which new badges were introduced to Stack Overflow?

Cheer,

Slotishtype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already begin with [this Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) and search all iteration of the word badges.

**EDIT:** For the early history of badges, from the first badge in August 2008 until December 2009, you can go to [this link](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/).

Comment: In fairness, he/she was the quickest.  As always, thanks.  j

Comment: @slotishtype, no he was not (difference is 9 seconds), but no problem ;-).

Comment: @slotishtype, as @Gamecat pointed I wasn't. Feel free to change your accepted answer if you wish. Also, I am a "he". :)

Comment: Guys, the badges only go back to 22-05-2010 - the last introduction is the generalist badge....but badges are constantly being introduced....Maybe I could get the first introduction of a badge from the data explorer?

Comment: @slotishtype, I added a link which list the badges created in 2008 and 2009. Well in fact in the blog, there is link corresponding for the creation of each batch of badges. The only badges which don't have such a link are Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges.

Answer (score 2):

Not for the badges, but have a look at [recent feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange), it contains all feature changes including the badges.

Comment: If only I saw the question 10 seconds earlier. XD

Comment: @Eldros, its only 9 seconds. But it isn't a big deal. As long as the answers are correct.

Comment: that's why I said 10, then I would have been able to answer before you. But mostly, I'm joking, as you said, the principle is to give a right answer.